# Setup composer package Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, composer-php, laravel-blade

i'm new in Laravel (5.6) and i'd like to know what's the **correct way** to install and setup a composer package in the framework, this in particular: https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin (It's a Jquery plugin)

I've read almost all the docs but i don´t understand. I've installed it via composer. Everything is ok, but i can´t get it working:

Coposer.json

```
 "require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "igorescobar/jquery-mask-plugin": "^1.14",
```

Now should i use one of the following in my controller?

```
use JqueryMaskPlugin;
use Igorescobar\JqueryMaskPlugin;
```

Or maybe loading it in the view?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('igorescobar/jquery-mask-plugin') }}"></script>
//Is there a 'vendor asset' blade shortcut?
```

Thanks and sorry for my english! =)

Comment: please use bower or npm. composer is the dependency manager of php libraries.

Comment: can you show me the output of the console?

Comment: @JeeskDenny I switched to npm, what's the next step now?
Do i have to put some namespace declaration?

Comment: I think the documentation explains it all. http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#basic-usage @Theo

Comment: add the file `<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.mask.js"></script>` in the view

Comment: Now the plugin is at `"node_modules/jquery-mask-plugin"`. 

`"../src/jquery.mask.js"` should be replaced with `"node_modules/jquery-mask-plugin/src/jquery.mask.js"` ??
Isn't there a "laravel way" of loading plugins? I'm bit lost with this point